# Using AJAX to set selected language in Wordpress Session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, session

I want to use a session in WordPress to store language selected by site visitors so that I can check the session and set the language in my site. I am new to WordPress so, I cannot figure out how would I go about calling a PHP file and setting the session data using jQuery. Am I going the wrong way about doing this? Is there an easier way of storing these variables and using them to change the front-end in WordPress?

I am trying to call a custom PHP script from jQuery as :

```
 jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "set-language.php",
       data: 'en',
 });
```

but I am getting a 404 not found error.

Comment: Don’t do this by trying to directly target your own script file, use the way AJAX is supposed to be handled in WP: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple Example

```
data = {};
data.action = 'change_language';
data.language = 'en';    

jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data, function ( response ) {
    console.log( response ); // just for debugging
    alert( response.some_more_data );   
} );
```

`ajaxurl` is provided by wordpress and points to *wp-admin/admin-ajax.php* (only on backend, in frontend you have to set it before with `<php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>`)

**PHP-Code:**

```
// place this in your functions.php or where you want
function ajax_language_changer() {
    
    $lang = $_REQUEST['language'];
    
    // do stuff to change the language
    
    $response = array(
        'request' => $_REQUEST, // just for debugging
        'what_ever_you_want' => 'mixed_data',
        'some_more_data' => 'Im done',
        '
    );
    
    wp_send_json( $response );
    
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_change_language', 'ajax_language_changer' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_change_language', 'ajax_language_changer' );
```

The hook `wp_ajax_nopriv_change_language` is for visitors (frontend). `wp_ajax_change_language` is for logged-in users. In this example ajax works for both.

Comment: `ajaxurl` is only defined in the admin, and not on the frontend. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190297/ajaxurl-not-defined-on-front-end

Comment: @Howard E: you are right, i have updated my answer accordingly.